# How to call widget with products of specific category in “.phtml” file?

Tags: magento2, phtml, widget

How can I call a widget that displays product from a specific category in a phtml file?

Currently I can only display "all_products" in my phtml file like that:

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")-  >setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("5")-  >setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml();

How to do this with products from specific category and not all products?

Answer (score 0):

You can create it programmatically as follows:

```
echo $productsBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList::class)
            ->setTitle("Featured Products")
            ->setProductsCount(10)
            ->setTemplate("product/widget/content/grid.phtml")
            ->setConditionsEncoded("a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`16`;]]");
            ->toHtml();
```